# how to add Following button on user page in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to implement the a **follow** button on user profile in asp.net (not social following button). what is the db schema? 
thank you

Comment: are u asking for sql for follow button functionality?

Comment: SQL tables to implement follow button for user profile. like as on fb profile follow button.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table with two fields.

1) `user_id_followed` of user who is being followed.

2) `user_id_following` of users who are following user in `1`.

So one user can be followed by many users. And many users can follow anyone.

hope this helps

Comment: @jibran if it helped then how about accepting it?